# awk and extracting specific field more than once

Tags: awk, gawk

I've got many files with variables in them like

```
{$var1} some text {$var2} some other text
```

I'd like to give them to awk so that awk extracts them and gives a result like this:

```
file_name.htm - 8 : {$title}
file_name.htm - 10 : {$css_style}
file_name.htm - 33 : {$img_carte_image_02_over}
```

This is a piece of cake with this awk script:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN { }
match($0, /({.*\$.+})/, tab) {
  for (x=1; tab[x]; x++) {
    print FILENAME" - "FNR" : "substr($0, tab[x, "start"], tab[x, "length"])
  }
}
END { }
```

I'm calling it like this:

```
find website/ | grep -E '(html|htm)$' | xargs ./myh.sh | more
```

Everything works fine except when multiples variables are on the same line. In this case I get:

```
file_name.htm - 59 : {$var1}<br/>{$var2}
```

whereas I want:

```
file_name.htm - 59 : {$var1}
file_name.htm - 59 : {$var2}
```

Any idea how I could/should do?
Of course if you have another solution (with sed or whatever) it's ok for me!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you post an example of the awk input lines (one good, one bad at least)?

Comment: The array that `match` fills includes an entry for each captured group `()` rather than each substring the regex matches. So in your case, it's actually matching most of the line because the regex is greedy. See the regex in marco's answer for a technique to anchor it. Note that if you're not doing anything in `BEGIN` and `END` you can omit them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
awk '{
    line=$0; 
    while (match(line,/({[^$]*\$[^}]+})/)){
        print FILENAME,"-",FNR,":",substr(line,RSTART,RLENGTH);
        line=substr(line,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)
    }
}'
```

The cycle ends when match() returns 0, that is when line doesn't contain any other "{foo$bar}" strings; I used substr() to remove the part of the line which has been already scanned for matches.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a non-greedy regex in the match (http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.regex/Greedy.html).  Probably won't work, but just an idea.

Comment: AWK doesn't know how to do non-greedy.